# Getting error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type

Tags: c++

I have a nested class definition and get errors on applying a cast to the pointer to it. The following program compiles with the error:

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘void* Achild<T>::test(void*)’:
test.cpp:24:31: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘type name’ with no type [-fpermissive]
       ShortName::ptr = (const ShortName::Ptr*)input;
                               ^~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:24:25: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
       ShortName::ptr = (const ShortName::Ptr*)input;
                         ^~~~~
test.cpp:24:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
       ShortName::ptr = (const ShortName::Ptr*)input;
                        ~^~~~~
                         )
test.cpp:25:6: warning: no return statement in function returning non-void [-Wreturn-type]
      }
```

I can't understand why i am getting errors on line 24. Any help would be appreciated!

```
template<typename T>
   class VeryLongName
   {
     public:
         class Ptr
         {
                 public:
                         int a;
                         Ptr() = default;
         };
         const Ptr* ptr;

   };

   template <typename T>
   class Achild: public VeryLongName<T>
   {
     using ShortName = VeryLongName<T>;
   public:
     Achild<T>() = default;

     void test(void * input)
     {
             ShortName::ptr = (const ShortName::Ptr*)input;
     }

   };

int main()
{
        auto *achild = new Achild<int>();
        auto a = new VeryLongName<int>::Ptr();
        achild->test((void*)a);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing a `typename` declaration:

```cpp
ShortName::ptr = (const typename ShortName::Ptr*) input;
```

as `ShortName` depends on your template type.

Comment: This fixed it. Doesn't `ShortName` already carry the template type (`VeryLongName<T>`)?

Comment: @CaptainJacksparrow `typename` is needed when the class type left of `::` is a dependent type. An `X<Y>::name` syntax is one common way for that to happen. Moving `X<Y>` to an alias `using Z = X<Y>;` just means `Z` is another dependent type, so the `typename` is still needed for `Z::name`.